# How is it true that all linear combinations of 2 distinct eigenvectors of a Hermetian operator share the same eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

Given a Hermitian operator $L$ and 2 distinct eigenvectors $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ with the same eigenvalue $\lambda$ (confusing to use $\lambda$ for both but that's what the book does), why is the following statement obvious, or even true?

> It should be clear that any linear combination of the two eigenvectors is also an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue.

It's clear to me that the linear combination $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ would have the same eigenvalue of $\lambda$ because they must be orthogonal. But for example wouldn't the linear combination $2\lambda_1+3\lambda_2$ have a different eigenvalue?

I'm kind of learning linear algebra on the fly so I may be misreading the statement altogether. I'm trying to break things down into components but still not seeing how the above statement is true.

Comment: They're fixing an eigenvalue and saying that all eigenvectors corresponding to that fixed eigenvalue forms a subspace.

Comment: I realized later that I was imagining the vectors (geometrically) incorrectly. I was thinking, how can the coefficients not add to the relative length of the vector and thus need a different eigenvalue. But the eigenvalue is relative to the larger vector to begin with. Novice mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure how the length of a vector comes in? Eigenvector corresponding to two different eigenvalues don't add to give you a third eigenvector corresponding to another eigenvalue. Keep in mind the identity map, where the whole space corresponds to the eigenvalue 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be an linear mapping and $x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n$ be its eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue $\lambda$. Let $c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n$ be scalars and put $x=\Sigma c_ix_i$. Then $Ax=\Sigma Ac_ix_i=\Sigma c_iAx_i=\Sigma c_i\lambda x_i=\lambda\Sigma c_ix_i=\lambda x$.